# Fire event to start draggable

Tags: kineticjs

I have a question about draggable.

Examplecode:

```
var kr: Kinetic.Rect = new Kinetic.Rect( ...) ;
kr.draggable(true);
kr.dragBoundFunc((pos) => {
   return this.MyFunctionForPositioning(pos);
});
```

I have to create the Kinetic.Rect on the fly, add it to a layer and the problem is that it doesn't move.

I think the draggable property needs to be invoke by some event so that my rect moves.

Does someone know which event to fire so that kr.draggable(true) starts without a mouseclick?

Answer (score 0):

kr.draggable(true) will enable dragging on kr.

The problem must be in your dragBoundFunc.